# Añadir una excepcion para cuando el buscador no obtiene resultados

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Estoy haciendo un buscador, cuando se hace la consulta a la BBDD a través del formulario obtiene los resultados, pero me gustaría añadir una excepción de que si el resultado de busqueda es 0 lo redirija a una pagina llamada error.html

Código formulario:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Prueba Buscador Ayudas Invepat</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="resultados.php" method="post">
        <label for="provincias">Provincia: </label>
        <select name="provincias" id="provincias">
            <option value="CORDOBA">Córdoba</option>
            <option value="SEVILLA">Sevilla</option>
            <option value="MALAGA">Málaga</option>
            <option value="CADIZ">Cádiz</option>
            <option value="HUELVA">Huelva</option>
            <option value="JAEN">Jaén</option>
            <option value="GRANADA">Granada</option>
            <option value="ALMERIA">Almería</option>
        </select>
        <label for="sectores">Sector: </label>
        <select name="sectores" id="sectores">
            <option value="HOSTELERO">Hostelero</option>
            <option value="HOTELERO">Hotelero</option>
            <option value="INDUSTRIA">Industria</option>
            <option value="AGRICOLA">Agrícola</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Ver ayudas</button>
    </form>




</body>
</html>
```

El resultado se muestra en una tabla sencilla:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Nombre Ayuda</th>
        <th>Fecha fin</th>
    </tr>


<?php

include 'connection.php';

$sector = $_POST['sectores'];
$provincia = $_POST['provincias'];



$consulta = "SELECT * from ayudas where sector='$sector' and provincia='$provincia'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$consulta);

if (mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)==0){
    header('Location: error.html');
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td>".$row['nombre_ayuda']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['fecha_fin']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    
}







?>
</html>
```

La redirección funciona correctamente, si por ejemplo elijo HUELVA INDUSTRIA, en la base de datos no ha nada con esas opciones por lo que redirige, pero si vamos a una busqueda correcta me "borra" el primer registro.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *... pero si vamos a una busqueda correcta me "borra" el primer registro.*

No es exactamente eso lo que ocurre. Es importante entender que cuando lanzas una consulta con mysqli, lo que recibes es un recurso o puntero hacia los datos. Significa que debes leer ese recurso para ir sacando los datos fila por fila. Para eso son precisamente los métodos *fetch_*  de mysqli.

Lo que ocurre en tu caso es que, haya datos o no, el código siempre pasa por aquí:

```
if (mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)==0){
    header('Location: error.html');
}
```

Y ahí, aplicas un `fetch_` a los resultados, es decir, mueves el puntero una vez, que equivale a **leer la primera fila de resultados**. De modo que cuando llegas a este punto:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    // ...
}
```

El puntero se encuentra ya **en la segunda fila de resultados**. Es importante entender que esa así como funciona para que no te encuentres rápidamente perdido trabajando con resultados obtenidos mediante mysqli.

Por otra parte, el `if` que usas para saber si hay filas no es correcto. Como ya dijimos `$result` es un recurso (un objeto statement) o `false`, si la consulta falla (revisa al respecto la documentación sobre `query()` en el Manual de PHP). Significa que ese `if` se cumplirá **solamente cuando la consulta falle,nunca cuando traiga cero filas**.

La forma más segura de verificar si existen datos en una consulta sería usar un `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM laTabla WHERE ...`  y verificar el total de filas devueltas. OJO a esto: quizá alguno te propondrá soluciones fáciles como usar `num_rows` (de hecho la red y Stackoverflow están llenas de respuestas basadas en esto). Ciertamente, `num_rows` es una propiedad del objeto que devuelve `query`, que contendría el total de filas que te devolvió la consulta. Pero es una solución precaria, aunque casi siempre funciona, `num_rows` podría depender de la configuración de buffer y de otros contextos, por lo que no siempre es segura. De todos modos, si optas por ella, revisa el Manual de PHP y también las notas de contribución para asegurar una configuración que no de margen a errores.

Sea como sea, la forma 100% segura de saber si hay datos es contando, con un `SELECT COUNT(*)`, como ya dije más arriba. O, dado que aquí necesitas usar los eventuales datos a posteriori (para completar tu tabla HTML), una solución factible sería guardar las filas en un array y luego verificar ese array: si está vacío no hay datos, si no está vacío hay datos.

Veamos una solución basada en esto último. Aprovechamos también para estructurar mejor el código. No es correcto empezar a mostrar contenido HTML para luego no saber si vas a redirigir o no. O una cosa o la otra, o la tabla completa (si hay datos) o la redirección (si no hay datos).

La cuestión es que cuando mandas encabezados, antes de ellos, no debería salir nada por pantalla, incluido el contenido HTML que tienes al principio.

Debes prestar atención también a cómo estructuras tu código. Por ejemplo, estás cerrando el `body` sin meter dentro la eventual tabla. Además, no tienes etiqueta de cierre para la tabla. Igualmente, la etiqueta `html` debe ser cerrada al final... Todo eso ha sido corregido.

```
<?php
    include 'connection.php';
    $sector = $_POST['sectores'];
    $provincia = $_POST['provincias'];
    $consulta = "SELECT * from ayudas where sector='$sector' and provincia='$provincia'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$consulta);
    /*
      Aquí guardaremos las filas 
    */
    $mData=array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      /*
        $mData se irá llenando con cada fila, si hay resultados 
      */
      $mData[]=$row;
    }

    /*
      Si no hay resultados, $mData estará vacío 
      y el código irá el else más abajo 
      OBSERVA que es aquí cuando creamos todo el HTML
    */
    if ($mData) {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <title>Document</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre Ayuda</th>
                <th>Fecha fin</th>
            </tr>

<?php  
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$mData['nombre_ayuda']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$mData['fecha_fin']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
    
<?php  

    } else {
      header('Location: error.html');
    }
```

### Post-Data

- Tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Debería considerar el uso de consultas preparadas para neutralizar ese riesgo.
- Cuando trabajes con super globales verifica siempre con isset, con empty o de otro modo. Podrías tener escenarios de *undefined index*.